# Google Chart-Table: Formatting Specific Cells with CSS

Tags: css, html-table, google-visualization

Starting to dive a bit in CSS and I have a simple Google Visualization as a Table where I am trying to format the table to look a bit cleaner.  However, the CSS Properties available in the Google Developer documentation appear to be very limited.

Is there another way to perhaps use a Global CSS to style the Google Visualization Table?

I've been able to do some basic formatting (see code below) but I am trying to make the Google Visualization Table match the formatting in the source Google Sheet.

Google Sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WvvhICEe1EpE_Y8jKMWTzuVjDLXl6rUperH2fkhsOtE/edit#gid=0

Specifically, these two items are the major road blocks...

1) Making the background of blank columns (or cells) be a specific color (ex green).  Tried using empty-cell in CSS but nothing really happens.

2) Making the text in the first column be LEFT aligned while the text in all the other columns is CENTER aligned.  The tableCell property from the Google documentation impacts all cells and not sure how to exclude the ones in the first column.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<div id="table_div" style="width: 700px; height: 400px;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart', 'table']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization1);
function drawVisualization1() {   
 var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WvvhICEe1EpE_Y8jKMWTzuVjDLXl6rUperH2fkhsOtE/gviz/tq?gid=0&headers=1&tq?&range=A1:F6');
  query.setRefreshInterval(10)
  query.send(handleQueryResponse1);
}
function handleQueryResponse1(response) {
  if (response.isError()) {
    alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
    return;
  }
  var data = response.getDataTable();
  var cssClassNames = {
headerRow: '',
tableRow: '',
oddTableRow: '',
selectedTableRow: '',
hoverTableRow: '',
headerCell: 'blue-background',
tableCell: '',};
  var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
  table.draw(data, {showRowNumber: false, allowHtml: true, width: '100%', height: '100%', cssClassNames: cssClassNames});
}
</script>
```

This is the CSS for the header

```
.blue-background {
   background-color: #c9daf8;
   word-wrap: normal;
  }
```

Comment: I think you got the solution? Can you self-answer this please?

Comment: Nope, if you look at what I have in jsfidddle, I do not have points 1 & 2 figured out =(

Answer (score 1):

Found an easy solution.  Ignore all the Google Documentation cssClassNames and simply assign a unique CSS class to the container then style as you would any other table.

This code snippet is how I added a unique CSS class:

```
<table id="table_div" class="table_style" style="width: 700px; height: 400px;"></table>
```

Then I just used that to style anything in the table.  Example:

```
.table_style td:nth-child(3),
.table_style td:nth-child(6) {
background: #27b399;
border: none;
}
```

**EDIT: This only works in jsfiddle but does not work when actually applied in my webpage.  Some default google table css overrides all my css even if I use !important.**

Comment: see the [data format](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table#data-format) for the Table chart, you can assign a css class directly to the cell by using a data table cell property, with name = `className`